# Trying to update graph using CSV

Tags: animation

I have a question. I am trying to plot a live graph while continuously updating a CSV file continuously from a LIDAR sensor. However when I call animation.FuncAnimation(... the graph does not continuously update. If I rerun, I see the graph updated. When I view the CSV file, I see has been updating.

```
class SecondGraph:
    def animate(i):
        graph_data = open(NameofCSV,'r').read()
        lines = graph_data.split('\n')
        xs = []
        ys = []
        for line in lines:
            if len(line) > 0:
                x, y = line.split(' ')
                xs.append(float(x))
                ys.append(float(y))
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(ys, xs)
```

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, SecondGraph.animate, interval=10)
```

When someone has a chance, can someone guide me in the right direction here. I do not think I need to plot my full code, but if you need to see it. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. I think I know the answer. The CSV does not update automatically, which may be the problem. I do not think there is anything wrong with my code that I posted.